# как работает ввод аргументов в функцию?

Tags: python, функции

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums, target):
        solList = []
        for i in range (0, len(nums)):
            for j in range (i+1, len(nums)):
                if nums[i]+nums[j] == target:
                    solList = solList.append(i)
                    solList = solList.append(j)
                    return solList

nums = [2, 7, 11, 15]
target = 9
Solution.twoSum(nums, target)
```

первая задачка с литкода

как передавать nums и target в функцию twoSum

помогите новичку

Comment: `Solution().twoSum(nums, target)`

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: append ничего не возвращает. просто solList.append(i)

Comment: я не понимаю, можете пример работающего кода привести, пожалуйста?

Comment: что не понимаете ? просто не пишите  `solList =`

Comment: а как тогда получить список с ответом?

Comment: `res = Solution().twoSum(nums, target; print(res)`

Comment: опечатался `res = Solution().twoSum(nums, target); print(res)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Измените немножко вашу программу:

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums, target):
        solList = []
        for i in range (0, len(nums)):
            for j in range (i+1, len(nums)):
                if nums[i]+nums[j] == target:
                    solList.append(i)
                    solList.append(j)
                    return solList

nums = [2, 7, 11, 15]
target = 9
Solution().twoSum(nums, target)
```

и вы получите вывод

> ```
> [0, 1]
> ```

(очевидно, **индексы** чисел 2 и 7 в списке `nums`).

---

*Объяснение:*

1. Метод `.append()` возвращает `None` («ничто»), значит, первая из ваших команд

   ```
                solList = solList.append(i)
                solList = solList.append(j)
   ```

   присвоит переменной `solList` значение `None`. Таким образом, в переменной `solList` уже не будет никакого списка, и вторая команда закончит программу ошибкой, потому что невозможно применить метод `.append(j)` к значению `None`.

   *Решение:*
   Метод `.append()` *не возвращает новый список*, он **прямо меняет исходный**:

   ```
                solList.append(i)
                solList.append(j)
   ```
2. `twoSum()` это метод не для класса `Solution`, а метод для **объектов** этого класса.

   Значит, он не применяется прямо к классу:

   ```
   Solution.twoSum(nums, target)       # неправильно!
   ```

   Нужно сначала **создать объект** этого класса, к чему достаточно *добавить за его имя скобки,* и затем применить метод на таким образом созданный объект:

   ```
   Solution().twoSum(nums, target)
   ```